# how to fix 'x' is assignable to the constraint of type 'y', but 'y' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'x'

Tags: typescript

I am building a utility method that returns the extended type.

Somehow, my approach to building a method has the following compile error.

`Type '{ name: string; }' is not assignable to type 'A'. '{ name: string; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'A', but 'A' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Base'.`

```js
type Base = {
    name: string;
}

type Ex1 = Base & {other: string};
type Ex2 = Base & {another: string};

type OtherType = {
    name: string
}

const convert = <A extends Base>(other: OtherType): A => {
    const ret = {
        name: other.name
    };
    return ret;
}

const otherType = {name: 'hello'};

const ex1 = convert<Ex1>(otherType);
ex1.other = 'other Value';

const ex2 = convert<Ex2>(otherType);
ex2.another = 'another Value';
```

see [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgZ2gXigbwFBW1AdnAWwgC4oFgAnAS1wHMBuDAXww1EigFEAPARilTwkUAGToA9sAAWECqXLU6TRu2g8ATANiJoYtHFySZcspRq1lrVVADy02QBVwKdFhz4i8s3WasAxuK45FABuABussBaADwAglAQ3MAQuAAmCNpIAHwAFEaypHbGTpAAlKTxyFmuOCGBwRQQUaiYtbUeJFD5FAB0HW7YlrWNwACuFLhQI4wsGKHB3SUuaB2kAOQyADab4muWc-VRifyooREUwNE8vLmLzqWMxz3dWmsvAGpwm6MQa4wHQSO3E0p0C50uGlu9goSweGES6h6BheqDWyOhUE+31+9CAA)

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Your object `ex` value is `{name: 'hello'}` which is clearly not of `Ex` type. This is a good example for the compilation error message: You are returning a Base object in your method which is not an A object.

Comment: The signature `<A extends Base>(a: string): A` is nonsensical - you are promising to return an arbitrary subtype but your function doesn't take any argument allowing it to know what subtype should be returned. Imagine if you were running a restaurant where you promised customers they could get *literally any* kind of food and they didn't even have to tell the waiter their order.

Comment: @HTN I have updated the question please add your answer. Thank you helping :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `Base` for your return type too. Like this:

```
const f = <A extends Base>(a: string): A | Base => {
const ret = {
    name: a
};
   return ret;
}
```

See [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=2&pln=7&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgZ2gXigbwFBW1AdnAWwgC4oFgAnAS1wHMBuDAXww1EigFEAPKVeJFABk6APbAAFhAqly1Ok0YYAxqNzkoAMz5QAPAEEoEbsAi4AJgliIIAPgAUcWZRq0AlKUMAfa4OS30LBxVdWAoCggw1EwcWLxCEig4IOxFFPDIgFcKXAzgRhYVNQ1jHU1dHgcAcikAG1rRKrd6IA)

You edit your question so I have to edit my answer!

**Edit**
You can use `ret as A;` in your `convert` function. Like this:

```
const convert = <A extends Base>(other: OtherType): A  => {
const ret = {
    name: other.name
};
return ret as A;
}
```

See [Working sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=17&ssc=2&pln=12&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgZ2gXigbwFBW1AdnAWwgC4oFgAnAS1wHMBuDAXww1EigFEAPARilTwkUAGToA9sAAWECqXLU6TRu2g8ATANiJoYtHFySZcspRq1lrVVADy02QBVwKdFhz4i8s3WasAxuK45FABuABussBaADwAglAQ3MAQuAAmCNpIAHwAFEaypHbGTpAAlKTxAlmuOCGBwRQQUaiYtbUeJFD5FAB0HW7YlrWNwACuFLhQI1CIULGMLBihwd0lLmgdpADkMgA2u%20Jblkv1UYn8qKERFMDRPLy5q86ljOc93VpbHwBqcLujEC2jBOQTO3E0l0C11uGke9goaxeGES6h6Bg%20qC26PhUF%20-0B9CAA)

Answer (score 1):

With cast, you can do anything. However, what you want to achieve is the same as:

```js
type Base = {
    name: string;
}

type Ex1 = Base & {other: string};
type Ex2 = Base & {another: string};

type OtherType = {
    name2: string
}

const convertToBase = (other: OtherType): Base => ({
  name: other.name2
});

const otherType = {name2: 'hello'};

const ex1 = convertToBase(otherType) as Ex1;
ex1.other = 'other Value';

const ex2 = convertToBase(otherType) as Ex2;
ex2.another = 'another Value';
```

With that, at least, you are telling the truth, your method converts `OtherType` to `Base`, and not to `Ex1` or `Ex2`. By using cast, you can assign a new property to the object, but you lost the interest of using typescript for type check: If you forgot to assign `ex1.other = 'other Value';`, your `ex1` will still be recongnized as `Ex1` by typescript but it's not the truth:

```js
const ex1 = convertToBase(otherType) as Ex1;
// ex1.other = 'other Value'; // forgot to do this
console.log(ex1.other.toUpperCase()); // Got runtime error here
```

It would be better to do it with destructuring assignment:

```js
const ex1: Ex1 = {
  ...convertToBase(otherType),
  other: 'other Value',
};

const ex2: Ex2 = {
  ...convertToBase(otherType),
  another: 'another Value',
};

const ex3: Ex1 = {
  ...convertToBase(otherType),
  another: 'another Value', // Error here
};
```